Please be more careful with tags such as [cognitive-modeling]
One of the only ways I can still browse CogSci.SE is by using tags. However, it seems that people are not being careful with tags. Can we do something about this?
In particular, I was recently browsing the mathematical modeling proposal and wanted to link a user to our cognitive-modeling tag, only to realize it was embarassing. For example, all but about 3 of the front page for that tag were not actually about cognitive modeling. For example, all of the following questions (most of them really bad) were marked as cognitive modeling (I have removed the tag):

Everybody thinks everyone's doing it, so they do it, and everyone ends up doing it
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5040/29
What is it called when a person seeks to compare themselves to others?
Why do certain activities seem to co-occur with well learnt skills?
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5016/29
Why are most popular humans pets carnivores?
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/4983/29
Audio Inculcation and Learning
https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/4965/29
What traits does a man have, when he is apt to feeling threatened by strong women?

When I was more active on the site, I used to carefully re-tag questions, but I am unfortunately not very active anymore. A plea to the remaining active members: if you see a tag being misused, please remove it! If a question needs a tag, please add it!

I agree retagging is an important thing to do for all new questions, especially those questions asked by occasional users.
cognitive-modeling seems to be one that is incorrectly applied. I've also seen cognitive-psychology misapplied quite a lot.
In general, most questions should have one or two major subdiscipline tags and one or two specific tags.

I remember near the start when almost everything was tagged as cognitive-psychology and every new user would tag their question as cog-psych to the point that the tag was meaningless. However, now I am a little confused about when I would use tags like cognitive-neuroscience but not use cognitive-psychology.

This answer responds to @Squirrl's downvoted answer, but I'm choosing not to just add it as a comment because I think it implies another consideration for the OP...
Not choosing a tag is better than choosing a bad tag. One can comment on one's own question to request a new tag, or ask a meta-question here about the usefulness of a new tag one might have in mind. If possible, the site might be edited to suggest this in the bar on the right that provides other instructions tag usage. This would also serve the goal of making users more aware of meta-sites, on which participation is much lower routinely.

Make sure there are enough tags.  If upon posting you're forced to choose one, and not a high enough level to create a new one, you may have no other option but to pick an incorrect one.   
